# How to return a array list with unique counts in VBScript

Tags: arraylist, vbscript

I'm very new to VBScript, I would show the sample data and how I want the outcome in an array list:

sample data:

```
  Variable 1               Variable 2
   Feb-18           6ce3f076-ffa8-4902-a33a-019c6534a79f
   Feb-18           6ce3f076-ffa8-4902-a33a-019c6534a79f
   Feb-18           6ce3f076-ffa8-4902-a33a-019c6534a79f
   Feb-18           6ce3f076-ffa8-4902-a33a-019c6534a79f
   Feb-18           6ce3f076-ffa8-4902-a33a-019c6534a79f
   Feb-18           97f8eb8e-877f-4e00-80e0-9d8de22f47fd
   Feb-18           97f8eb8e-877f-4e00-80e0-9d8de22f47fd
   Feb-18           Unassigned
   Apr-18           Unassigned
   May-18           Unassigned
   Jun-18           Unassigned
   Jul-18           Unassigned
   Aug-18           Unassigned
   Sep-18           Unassigned
   Dec-18           Unassigned
   Feb-18           Unassigned
```

I need the output as:

```
           new_Variable_1              new_Variable_2
6ce3f076-ffa8-4902-a33a-019c6534a79f         5
97f8eb8e-877f-4e00-80e0-9d8de22f47fd         2
Unassigned                                   9
```

I've tried many ways but not successful.

Can anyone help me in achieving this task using VBScript.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: Are `Variable1` and `Variable2` arrays? Edit the question, add the code you tried, show the issues you encountered.

Comment: @omegastripes: yes those are also arrays, what shall I add in the question?

Comment: Try to process array elements within loop, and store count data into dictionary, where keys are `Variable2` values.

Comment: @omegastripes Do you have any sample code which I can use for reference? As I told I'm not good with VBScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the below example:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim aVariable2, vItem, aResult1, aResult2

aVariable2 = Array("6ce3f076-ffa8-4902-a33a-019c6534a79f", "6ce3f076-ffa8-4902-a33a-019c6534a79f", "6ce3f076-ffa8-4902-a33a-019c6534a79f", "6ce3f076-ffa8-4902-a33a-019c6534a79f", "6ce3f076-ffa8-4902-a33a-019c6534a79f", "97f8eb8e-877f-4e00-80e0-9d8de22f47fd", "97f8eb8e-877f-4e00-80e0-9d8de22f47fd", "Unassigned", "Unassigned", "Unassigned", "Unassigned", "Unassigned", "Unassigned", "Unassigned", "Unassigned", "Unassigned")
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each vItem In aVariable2
        .Item(vItem) = .Item(vItem) + 1
    Next
    aResult1 = .Keys()
    aResult2 = .Items()
End With

MsgBox Join(aResult1, vbCrLf)
MsgBox Join(aResult2, vbCrLf)
```

Comment: Thanks mate it is very helpful, Hopefully it should do the thing